# Applying Sum if formula while setting date as a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a huge bulk of data in this form i.e.

```
Date           Item Code   Value    Customer Name     Customer ID
---------------------------------------------------------------
September-15   040007      118      Khizar   Tariq    14797
September-15   040156      11       Khizar   Tariq    14797
September-15   040875      2        Khizar   Tariq    14797
October-15     040040      169      Khizar   Tariq    14797
October-15     040875      5        Khizar   Tariq    14797
October-15     040366      7        Khizar   Tariq    14797
November-15    040557      57       Khizar   Tariq    14797
November-15    040314      11       Khizar   Tariq    14797
November-15    040833      12       Khizar   Tariq    14797
December-15    040875      3        Khizar   Tariq    14797
December-15    040113      6        Khizar   Tariq    14797
December-15    040156      11       Khizar   Tariq    14797
```

And i want to see its month wise summary in this format

```
Month         Total amount of month wise purchase
-------------------------------------------------
September-15  130 
October-15    180 
November-15   79 
December-15   20
```

Comment: In `Date` column are they date? Or string text?

Comment: Its date not string no

Comment: Reformat code for readability

Comment: Reformat code for readability

Comment: This is an excel related query. Don't know how to reformat code for readability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems easy enough.
 
Use the Subtotal button in the Outline group on the Data tab. There you can choose which column to sum or count etc. But, make sure you sort first on the column you want to have calculated.